# .htaccess blocking strange QueryString parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string

I've got some server pinging my Rails app and is appending 
").html(bodyText);$j("
to many of my pages.  Its generating all sorts of exceptions of routes not found.

Example of page call.
http://www.domain.com/bigmikes/).html(bodyText);$j(

I'm pretty green in terms of .htaccess and Mod_Rewrite

I'd like to either have it throw a 404 or a 301 redirect to 
http://www.domain.com/bigmikes/

Comment: Block the pinging site and tell the admin to fix his code before opening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is no ? character, I suspect that its not considered a query string parameter.

The problem is that apache is now looking for a directory called `).html(bodyText);$j(`

To stop that from happening, you can try writing a mod_rewrite which does a regex search for that exact string, or you can try making a directory by that name containing a file with a redirect in it. I know, it sucks.

But so does the person who wrote that code and forgot to close the quotes with your URL. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ")" in any of your URIs (the request before the ?), then why not just fail any URI which includes one:

```
RewriteRule \)|%29         -     [F]
```

I wouldn't try to "repair" broken URIs.  The request was invalid.